# Как обработать JSON с google sheets-api?

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, google-sheets-api

Для некоторых задач мне необходимо считать количество индексов в колонке.

Делаю я это с помощью подсчета строк, дальше собирался использовать `len`.
Вот код:

```
index = service.spreadsheets().values().get(
spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id,
range='B2:B',
majorDimension='ROWS').execute()
pprint(index)
```

Вот только на выходе получается JSON, который не дает мне посчитать количество элементов:

```
{
    'majorDimension': 'ROWS',
    'range': 'Sheet1!B2:B1000',
    'values': [
        ['Имя1'],
        ['Имя2'],
        ['Имя3'],
        ['Имя4'],
        ['Имя5'],
        ['Имя6'],
        ['Имя7'],
        ['Имя8'],
        ['Имя9'],
        ['Имя10'],
        ['Имя11'],
        ['Имя12'],
        ['Имя13']
    ]
}
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как обработать JSON так, чтобы в списке остались лишь элементы из ячеек?

Comment: [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), проголосуйте за ответ и отметьте его [галочкой](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) как решение.

Answer (score 3):

Преобразовать index из json в словарь:

```
 data = json.loads(index)
```

Посчитать количество словарей в values:

```
len_names = len(data['values'])
```